# Making an ActivityIndicator dissappear in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have some processes and [activity indicators](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Activity_indicator_1214556_11.jsp). When these processes are finished, I want these activity fields to disappear but not sure how to do it. All I can do is to cancel them but that doesn't make them go away. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the activity indicator field from the parent manager.

```java
public static void removeField(Field f) {
    Manager m = f.getManager();
    if(m != null) {
        m.delete(f);
    }
}
```